# Get docstring from script by Sphinx

Tags: python, package, python-sphinx

I have classical Python package structure:

```
bin/
    my_script
docs/
my_package/
   ...
```

and I create docs with Sphinx.

I would like to take docstring from `my_script` automatically. Is there any way to do it?

Why want I to do it? I have usage information in this script and I would like to show it in documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution - I don't think it's the best.

I created `__init__.py` in bin directory and symlink `my_script.py` to `my_script`. Into `conf.py` (config of sphinx) I added:

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..'))
```

Now I can use automodule:

```
.. automodule:: bin.my_script
```